# Create a PHP HTTP Request configuration of the current file in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, macros, phpstorm

[image: run configurations]

One of my favorite workflows in PhpStorm to debug PHP is creating a configuration of PHP HTTP Request but this option is a bit hard to access from the context menus. Doing right-click on a PHP file, it's possible to create a Run configuration for a PHP Script but not for a PHP HTTP Request. The PHP script configuration is not useful for me since it runs locally and the databases don't accept the requests that my code is trying to perform.

I have tried to do a macro for this process but my algorithm stops in some steps.

The steps I want to achieve are:

1. Copy the path of the current file.
2. Open "Edit configurations"
3. Create a new PHP HTTP Request
4. Paste the content of the clipboard into the field Name and URL
5. Select the last of the servers in the dropdown Servers.
6. Save the configuration and close the window.

What is the expected result?
Create a PHP HTTP Request of the current file.

What happens instead?
It takes a lot of small repetitive steps to achieve it and the macros aren't very helpful so far.

I have also posted this on the JetBrains forum: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-57243

Comment: *"I have also posted this on the Jetbrains forum"* That NOT a Forum. That's an Issue Tracker.

Comment: @LazyOne true. My bad.

Comment: Did you try debugging with an in-editor HTTP client instead? Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-a-php-http-request.html#debug-the-request-via-http-client

Comment: @Dmitrii Nice idea. I am trying to create the macro with the HTTP request instead but it looks like the process is still not successfully recorded. Some of the steps are not saved.